# Retain escape sequences and color when using sed

Tags: bash, sed, ansi-escape

I have output out of a test reporter that returns nicely colored results, and miscellaneous garbage I want to get rid of.  I tried using `sed` via:

```
karma start tests/karma.conf.js | sed 's|var.*browserify||'
```

...which removes the junk, but also kills the colored results.  How can I retain them?

Here's an example of the raw output before sed:

```
^[[1A^[[2KERROR: 'Unhandled promise rejection' /var/folders/xs/wmmjbz4s6mdgcqynwn46qtmr0000gn/T/799ac09c665c85beb20f6d99be27c1cf.browserify?c65c8d7afc187ee2ed8307a171bc8e1511bfb40b:91625:48)
```

Comment: you should provide the output of your `karma start...` command. with ansi-escape in literal string, so that we could know what are "garbage" and "junk", what are not.

Comment: The command produces lines that are colored, and have long source map references like  '/var/folders/xs/wmmjbz4s6mdgcqynwn46qtmr0000gn/T/5af9b10dfa0541017948b6e4c12e38ce.browserify'.  The colored text surrounding the junk changes depending on the test and the failure condition.

Comment: it seems that you didn't understand me. do this: `karam....|vim -` then you see the output with ansi-escape. then provide the expected result, that is, what do you want to change? (I knew you want to keep the ansi-escapes)

Comment: `.*` grabs the color sequences? use a more specific regex...

Comment: @Kent ok, I added an example line

Comment: that line won't match.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath updated the sed to reflect it. Theres lots of giberish in the output.  Is the idea that the regex im using is too broad?  I'm using BSD sed, if that makes a difference

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yep, you were right, the .* was the issue.  If you want credit ill accept your answer

Comment: @juwiley: normally I wouldn't, but this is going to be my xmass gift :) 1000 rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` will match everything, including color codes.

If you don't want to match them, use a more specific regex, e.g. a character range.

Answer (score 1):

For the given example,

```
/var/folders/xs/wmmjbz4s6mdgcqynwn46qtmr0000gn/T/799ac09c665c85beb20f6d99be27c1cf.browserify
```

a more-specific pattern might be one of these, using character classes:

```
sed 's|var[^[:cntrl:]]*browserify||'
sed 's|var[[:alnum:]./]*browserify||'
```

I would use the latter, since it would eliminate the possibility of skipping over a complete pathname (if more than one were given on a line).